# "fluent-ffmpeg" in node.js to add background audio on a video

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

Scenario : I have a mp4 video of 30sec with no background Audio. Now I want to add 3 background audios(mp3) on this video i.e. - [0-10s] 1st Audio next [10-20s] 2nd Audio and then last [20-30s] 3rd Audio by using fluent-ffmpeg. I have been searching a lot for this scenario but not getting right solution. Any lead in this much much appreciated.

**Note** - Whenever I'm searching, getting some solutions which is in ffmpeg native command line query but I need equivalent solution in respective of node "fluent-ffmpeg".

Comment: Convert the "native command" to fluent-ffmepg lib? What have you tried so far? Please complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.